# Rhyme scheme when words are the same and when words don't rhyme at all?

Tags: poetry

How do you identify the rhyme scheme between the lines of a poem when they end with the same word? For example:

> I like to think chess is a courteous **game**,
>   I play it with family and friends.
>   I like to think chess is a peaceful **game**,
>   Nobody gets hurt when it ends.

Is the rhyme scheme simply **ABAB** in this case?

And how about the rhyme scheme when the words don't rhyme at all?

> I never distract my **opponent**,
>   I don't want to act like a pest.
>   I hope they behave in the very same **way**,
>   So both of us play at our best.

Is it **XAXA** or **ABCB**?

Overall, is a rhyme scheme separate for each stanza or the poem on the whole? What are the relevant rules? (Relevant to the question, that is.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_4-line

Comment: @Nico You are referring to the second question, correct? So it'd be **ABCB** and not **XAXA**, I guess?

Comment: yes, that's how I understand it, but I'll keep searching when I find some time. I wouldn't be surprised if there were other notations.

Comment: X is generally used to refer to unrhymed lines, so either ABCB or XAXA is fine here. X never rhymes with itself, if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although 'game' and 'game' is an identical rhyme, because it is the same sound, I think this would be **ABAB** as you suggest.

You are also right that the second example would be **XAXA**. Nico is right that you could also write this **ABCB**; both are valid. Because X is a special notation for an unrhymed line, you might choose XAXA for clarity, particularly for longer stanzas. I prefer it, because you can immediately see which lines are rhymed, and which are not, without having to remember each letter and see if it has been used twice.

In terms of rules, I think it is common for the rhyme scheme to be separate for each stanza. A poem may follow an ABAB scheme throughout, so it is simpler to write ABAB ABAB ABAB, rather than ABAB CDCD EFEF. If there is a more complex overarching rhyme scheme which connects the stanzas, you might choose to use one scheme overall, e.g. ABAB CDCD ABAB CD AB.